# findNearest much slower in c++ than Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have very similar functions in python and c++ doing color segmentation, calling *findNearest*. The python performs around 15 FPS. C++ version is taking more than 10 seconds. measuring time I know that the big difference is on findNearest function. Any idea of the reason ? why the same opencv function called the same way is taking so long in c++ ?

Here are snapshots to picture the situation: (edited to show tickCount explicitly)

**python version**

```
def computeSimplified(frame):
    samples = np.float32(np.array(frame).reshape((-1, 3)))
    t0 = cv.getTickCount()
    ret, result, neigh, dist = knn.findNearest(samples, 5)
    t1 = cv.getTickCount()
    pixels = np.array([groupAvg[item[0].astype(np.int8)] for item in result])
    new_frame = pixels.reshape((np.shape(frame)))
    secs = (t1 - t0) / cv.getTickFrequency()
    print("img dimensions: {0} find nearest time: {1}".format(np.shape(frame), secs))
    return new_frame
```

**c++ version**

```
cv::Mat ColorMapper::computeReduced(cv::Mat img)
{
  cv::Mat samples, result, img_result;
  std::vector<int> original_shape {img.rows, img.cols};  //  rows, cols
  std::vector<int> new_shape {img.cols * img.rows, 3};  //  rows, cols

  img.reshape(1, new_shape).convertTo(samples, CV_32F);
  int64 t0 = cv::getTickCount();
  knn->findNearest(samples, 1, result);
  int64 t1 = cv::getTickCount();
  result.reshape(1, original_shape).convertTo(img_result, CV_8U);
  cv::Mat colored_result(original_shape, CV_8UC3);
  // Parallel execution using C++11 lambda.
  typedef cv::Point3_<uint8_t> Pixel;
  colored_result.forEach<Pixel>(
    [&](Pixel & p, const int * position) -> void {
      int color_class = img_result.at<int>(position[0], position[1]);
      int row = color_class / COLOR_DIM1_QTY;
      int col = color_class % COLOR_DIM1_QTY;
      p.x = avgColors[std::make_pair(row, col)][0];
      p.y = avgColors[std::make_pair(row, col)][1];
      p.z = avgColors[std::make_pair(row, col)][2];
    });
  double secs = (t1 - t0) / cv::getTickFrequency();
  RCLCPP_INFO(
    rclcpp::get_logger("vision_manager - ColorMapper"),
    "img. dimensions: %d %d find nearest time: %f", img.rows, img.cols, secs);
  return colored_result;
}
```

Here some outputs of the performance and dimensions:

**C++**

```
img. dimensions: 350 1936 find nearest time: 3.930569
```

**Python**

```
img dimensions: (450, 2464, 3) find nearest time: 0.025378171
```

I would expect that the c++ version were as performant as python's or better. Not sure what is happening or how to get better performance on c++ version. The only idea I can think of is to call findNearest per pixel inside the forEach, not tried yet. In any case I would expect, give the high similarity of both snapshots that the c++ would go faster.

c++ opencv version is 4.4 the build information is as follows:

```
 General configuration for OpenCV 4.4.0 =====================================
   Version control:               unknown
 
   Extra modules:
     Location (extra):            /home/nicolas/Documents/Libraries/opencv_contrib-4.4.0/modules
     Version control (extra):     unknown
 
   Platform:
     Timestamp:                   2022-11-07T18:52:40Z
     Host:                        Linux 5.15.0-52-generic x86_64
     CMake:                       3.16.3
     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
     Configuration:               RELEASE
 
   CPU/HW features:
     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
       requested:                 SSE3
     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
       requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
       SSE4_1 (17 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
       SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
       FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
       AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
       AVX2 (31 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
       AVX512_SKX (7 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX
 
   C/C++:
     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
     C++ standard:                11
     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 9.4.0)
     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/gcc-9
     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
     ccache:                      NO
     Precompiled headers:         NO
     Extra dependencies:          m pthread cudart_static -lpthread dl rt nppc nppial nppicc nppidei nppif nppig nppim nppist nppisu nppitc npps cublas cudnn cufft -L/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
     3rdparty dependencies:
 
   OpenCV modules:
     To be built:                 alphamat aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy gapi hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality rapid reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab viz xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
     Disabled:                    cudacodec world
     Disabled by dependency:      -
     Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cvv java js julia matlab ovis python2 sfm
     Applications:                tests perf_tests examples apps
     Documentation:               NO
     Non-free algorithms:         YES
 
   GUI: 
     GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.24.20)
       GThread :                  YES (ver 2.64.6)
       GtkGlExt:                  NO
     OpenGL support:              NO
     VTK support:                 YES (ver 7.1.1)
 
   Media I/O: 
     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
     WEBP:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x020e)
     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.37)
     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.1.0)
     JPEG 2000:                   OpenJPEG (ver 2.3.1)
     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2_3)
     HDR:                         YES
     SUNRASTER:                   YES
     PXM:                         YES
     PFM:                         YES
 
   Video I/O:
     DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
     FFMPEG:                      YES
       avcodec:                   YES (58.54.100)
       avformat:                  YES (58.29.100)
       avutil:                    YES (56.31.100)
       swscale:                   YES (5.5.100)
       avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
     GStreamer:                   YES (1.16.3)
     v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
 
   Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2020.1 interface 11101)
 
   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
 
   Other third-party libraries:
     Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
            at:                   /home/nicolas/Documents/Libraries/opencv-4.4.0/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
               at:                /home/nicolas/Documents/Libraries/opencv-4.4.0/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
     Lapack:                      NO
     Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.7)
     Custom HAL:                  NO
     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
 
   NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 11.7, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
     NVIDIA GPU arch:             86
     NVIDIA PTX archs:
 
   cuDNN:                         YES (ver 8.6.0)
 
   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
     Include path:                /home/nicolas/Documents/Libraries/opencv-4.4.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
 
   Python 3:
     Interpreter:                 /home/nicolas/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python3 (ver 3.8.10)
     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so (ver 3.8.10)
     numpy:                       /home/nicolas/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.23.4)
     install path:                /home/nicolas/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/python-3.8
 
   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
 
   Java:                          
     ant:                         NO
     JNI:                         NO
     Java wrappers:               NO
     Java tests:                  NO
 
   Install to:                    /usr/local
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Python version of cv.getBuildInformation():

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.4.0 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            /home/nicolas/Documents/Libraries/opencv_contrib-4.4.0/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2022-11-07T18:52:40Z
    Host:                        Linux 5.15.0-52-generic x86_64
    CMake:                       3.16.3
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    Configuration:               RELEASE

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (17 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (31 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (7 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 9.4.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/gcc-9
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          m pthread cudart_static -lpthread dl rt nppc nppial nppicc nppidei nppif nppig nppim nppist nppisu nppitc npps cublas cudnn cufft -L/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 alphamat aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy gapi hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality rapid reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab viz xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    cudacodec world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cvv java js julia matlab ovis python2 sfm
    Applications:                tests perf_tests examples apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         YES

  GUI: 
    GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.24.20)
      GThread :                  YES (ver 2.64.6)
      GtkGlExt:                  NO
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 YES (ver 7.1.1)

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
    WEBP:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.1.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   OpenJPEG (ver 2.3.1)
    OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2_3)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (58.54.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.29.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.31.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.5.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   YES (1.16.3)
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)

  Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2020.1 interface 11101)

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   /home/nicolas/Documents/Libraries/opencv-4.4.0/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                /home/nicolas/Documents/Libraries/opencv-4.4.0/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.7)
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 11.7, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             86
    NVIDIA PTX archs:

  cuDNN:                         YES (ver 8.6.0)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /home/nicolas/Documents/Libraries/opencv-4.4.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /home/nicolas/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python3 (ver 3.8.10)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so (ver 3.8.10)
    numpy:                       /home/nicolas/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.23.4)
    install path:                /home/nicolas/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/python-3.8

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /usr/local
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also here is the relevant extract of the CMakeList.txt. Used to compile c++ version:

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
```

Comment: do both versions give the same result, apart from differing execution time? how exactly did you measure execution times? please getBuildInformation() from both.

Comment: `C++ flags (Release):` -- Are you running the release build or the debug build?  If it is the debug build, please try the release build.

Comment: Hi @PaulMcKenzie, I thought that the line `Configuration: RELEASE` in the build information I paste was enough. Should I check anything else ?

Comment: yes, everything would be good. _everything_. see if both reports fit in the question. if they don't, you could post them on an appropriate pastebin. https://gist.github.com works fine. others are okay too. avoid "markdown" or "writing" pastebins. they can't handle text with symbols that programmers use.

Comment: and we still need to know exactly _what_ pieces of code you measured the execution time of, and how you did that. that loop in your C++ code may take extra time. and so would the list comprehension in your Python code.

Comment: @user2015606 -- You have both `Debug` and `Release` settings.  Which version of the program are you actually running?

Comment: `Configuration: RELEASE` would indicate the choice for the C++ situation. still doesn't mean all that much. opencv can employ various acceleration strategies. this depends on what it was compiled to do.

Comment: Hi everyone, I tried to add more information and added to the shared code explicitly how is the time measured. Also added some extracts of the CMakeLists.txt of C++ and the python version of cv.getBuildInformation()

Comment: both reports are identical. looks like you built OpenCV yourself, and it's the same build in both cases (Python, C++)...  did I get that right? if so, I find this difference in performance puzzling. perhaps the package loader for Python performs some initialization, or finds some DLLs, which somehow is not the case when you run this from C++... please inspect resource usage. do you see your GPU getting taxed by the Python code, but not the C++ code? what do the CPU cores do? you could put the `findNearest()` in a loop to keep the system busy long enough to observe resource usage

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz OK I will make that loop and look for any differences. BTW, system is Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: And yes, I compiled opencv and I'm using same build in both cases.